# How to make my scanner app look like Fooducate on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, barcode-scanner

The Fooducate app ( on left below ) shows a large video preview for their scanner.  The scanner ONLY detects barcodes in the bright area between the white arrows.

My ViewController's view ( on right below ) has a subview that displays the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.  The video preview only shows up there.

How do I make my video preview look like theirs and ONLY target scanning in the non-grey area?

Class used for

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class Scanner: NSObject, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

var device: AVCaptureDevice?
var metadata: AVCaptureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
var cameraLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
var session: AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var videoIn: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
var queue : dispatch_queue_t

init() {
    cameraLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
    cameraLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.zombie.shopper.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    println("scanner init")
}

func setupScanner() {
    device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if !device {
        println("No video device found!")
        return
    }

    var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
    videoIn = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device, error: error)
    if session.canAddInput(videoIn) {
        session.addInput(videoIn)
    }
    if session.canAddOutput(metadata) {
        session.addOutput(metadata)
    }

    metadata.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    metadata.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
                                    AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code  // UPC-A
                                    ];
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects:      AnyObject[]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    if (metadataObjects.count > 0) {
        println("beep: \(metadataObjects.count), start index: \(metadataObjects.startIndex)")
        println("[0] = \(metadataObjects[0])")
    }
}
}
```

Here is how it's laid out visually.  previewView below is the IBOutlet from the Storyboard

```
  scanner.cameraLayer.frame = previewView.bounds
  previewView.layer.addSublayer(scanner.cameraLayer)
```

[image: fooducate scanner ios]
[image]

Comment: What exactly is the end result you would like to achieve and what problems are you having accomplishing that result?

Comment: Just updated, hopefully the question at the end clarifies.  I know how to make the video preview larger ... that's easy.  I don't know how to make the scanning only look in the non-grey area like Fooducate does.

Comment: Can you add the code where set up the AVAudioSession?

Comment: Added the code used to setup the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Can you please show your AVAudioSession

Comment: There is no AVAudioSession

Comment: My bad, AVCaptureSession.

Comment: Couldn't you theoretically capture everything (and make your view fullscreen), while manually creating the blackish overlay and only analyze the upper part of the recording?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have your session set up something along the lines of:

```
AVCaptureSession *session = ...
...
AVCaptureMetadataOutput *output = ...
```

There is a property on `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` called `rectOfIntersect`. From Apple's documentation, the description is this:

> Specifying a rectangle of interest may improve detection performance
>   for certain types of metadata. Metadata objects whose bounds do not
>   intersect with the rectOfInterest will not be returned.

Basically this will allow you to customize the rect that you want to detect your barcodes in.

You could try something like this: `output.rectOfInterest = CGRectMake(x,y, 0.5, 0.5)`. This creates a rect that is half the width of the preview window. The default is `(0,0,1,1)`.

Comment: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5) finds objects in the upper right corner.  I would have expected it to be the upper left.

Comment: @drfence you're correct. It does do the upper left corner. You'll have to fiddle with it. Actually you could do output.rectOfInterest = cameraLayer.bounds which meets your needs if you haven't done so already